# Drop rows of a dataframe based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrames:

df1

```
ID  Name     Date
1     A     19-02-2020 18:24:32
2     B     17-02-2020 16:43:52
3     C     05-02-2020 08:28:12
4     D     29-02-2020 23:32:05
5     E     01-02-2020 04:56:07
```

df2

```
ID  Name     Date
1     A     19-02-2020 17:24:32
2     B     17-02-2020 19:43:52
3     C     05-02-2020 10:28:12
4     D     29-02-2020 17:32:05
5     E     01-02-2020 05:56:07
```

Now I have to drop the rows in df1 such that date of respective ID/Name should be less than df2, resulting in

res_df

```
ID  Name     Date
2     B     17-02-2020 16:43:52
3     C     05-02-2020 08:28:12
5     E     01-02-2020 04:56:07
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to unite the DF with [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), filter the data with [`.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)  the extra columns created during the process

```
(
   df1.merge(df2, on = ['ID', 'Name'], suffixes=['', '_y'])
     .query('Date < Date_y')
     .drop(columns=['Date_y'])
)
#output:
    ID  Name    Date
0   2   B       2020-02-17 16:43:52
1   3   C       2020-05-02 08:28:12
2   5   E       2020-01-02 04:56:07
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['ID', 'Name'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['ID', 'Name'])
cond = df1.Date < df2.Date
print(df1[cond].reset_index())
```

Comment: this is a nice way to do this +1